# Run Python script on Linux kernel namespace

Tags: python, linux-kernel, namespaces

I have entered a difficult question with Python running on Linux. When I want to run a python script on a Linux kernel namespace, I can do "sudo ip netns exec mynamespace python myscript.py". If I run myscript.py directly, how can I do the same approach?

Comment: Interpreting the shebang in the first line is a feature of the shell. If the ip tool does not support it you have to call the interpreted directly. Many system tools do allow running binaries only for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Rest of your script
```

That should do it.